# Pulling .live() functionality out of jQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon, dom-events, xul

I am writing a Firefox Add-On that currently is depending on jQuery for the following things:

- Selectors
- Animations
- A special .live("focus") hail-mary event-catching manoeuvre that happens to work with jQuery 1.4.2 (but not 1.4.4)

jQuery isn't well suited for functioning inside XUL, and it's a miracle we've gotten this far with it.  We're trying to remove the jQuery requirements, the first two are easy (animations are simple, and we can use `.querySelector()` instead of jQuery), but the `.live` has proven impossible to do on our own.  I've tried reading the source code, but I haven't been able to piece it apart.

**What is the jQuery .live function doing?  There's clearly a lot more going on** than document.addEventListener("focus"/"focusin",function_to_pick_apart_events).  What else is going on here?

Comment: How complicated is your `live` selector? Depending on that you might be able to implement a replacement that just works with that (or same structured selectors).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, using JQuery in a Firefox addon may not be as hopeless as it sounds. But to answer your question directly: JQuery is open-source, so you can always look for yourself. I'm not familiar with the JQuery source code myself, but I think https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L552 might be a good place to start...

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to capture focus events at the window level, then loop through looking for elements of interest that might not already have a focus event listener and add one. An over-simplified example:

```
<script>
function handleFocus(event) {
  event.target.value = "";
}
function captureFocus() {
  document.getElementById("target").onfocus = handleFocus;
}
window.onload = function() {
  addEventListener("focus", captureFocus, true);
}
</script>
<input id="target" value="Enter the value">
```

As you can see there is no requirement for the input to exist in the document when the script executes, it will attach the event listener on the first focus event instead.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running JQuery in noConflict mode?  I have some colleagues that swear by JQuery in Firefox Add-ons.  I've seen their work, both the result and the code, and it's fantastic.  I suggest noConflict mode, and use jQuery to refer to JQuery instead of the $ symbol.

.live is different than .bind.  In fact, live is pretty amazing.  It not only binds event handlers to elements matching a specific CSS selector, but will also bind the handler to any new elements that are imported onto the page that match that selector.  There clearly must be some kind of monitoring going on under the hood to continue to bind events to new elements, **EDIT**: such as the event bubbling delegation described in the comments below.

Considering XUL has a different structure than the HTML DOM, this could explain why you have trouble with .live.

A possible workaround could be to use .bind and then add handlers to any new elements yourself, if that is indeed your goal of using .live.  Essentially, if you add new elements on the page that match the selector, you'll need to bind any events to those elements that would have been bound had those elements existed on window load.

Comment: Yes - this is definitely not the problem.  It's also important to follow the advice of this guy: http://meherranjan.com/blog/a-guide-to-using-jquery-inside-firefox-extension/ - who enumerates the changes you have to make (yes, code changes) to jQuery to avoid massive headaches.  We ended up having to reinvent that wheel - but sometimes finding resources late is better than never.  In any case, jQuery is great - but it's a whole lot of extra code to load in to every single XUL window.

Comment: *"It not only binds event handlers to elements matching a specific CSS selector, but will also bind the handler to any new elements that are imported onto the page that match that selector. There clearly must be some kind of monitoring going on..."* The `.live()` method doesn't work like that at all. It uses event delegation on the `document` level. Events that bubble up to the `document` are tested against selectors that were associated with that event type. If an element matches a selector, the handler is invoked. If propagation of the event is stopped, `.live()` won't work.

Comment: Interesting... Does that apply to XUL DOM also?

Comment: I don't know from experience whether it would also apply to the XUL but my guess is that it would. Try it and see...